# Fast algorithm for simple data group

Tags: algorithm

There are several billions rows like this

```
id | type | groupId
---+------+--------
1  |  a   |  
1  |  b   |  
2  |  a   |
2  |  c   |
1  |  a   |  
2  |  d   |  
2  |  a   |
1  |  e   |
5  |  a   |
1  |  f   |
4  |  a   |
1  |  b   |
4  |  a   |
1  |  t   |
8  |  a   |
3  |  c   |
6  |  a   |
```

I need to add groupId for these data, if id same or type same, then its a same groupId, the result like this:

```
id | type | group
---+------+--------
1  |  a   |  1
1  |  b   |  1
2  |  a   |  1
2  |  c   |  1
1  |  a   |  1
2  |  d   |  1
2  |  a   |  1
1  |  e   |  1
5  |  a   |  1
1  |  f   |  1
4  |  a   |  1
1  |  b   |  1
4  |  a   |  1
7  |  t   |  2
8  |  g   |  3
3  |  c   |  1
6  |  a   |  1
```

I try to use a loop to do this, but its very inefficiency, its need server weeks to finish all this.

Comment: show your algorithm.

Answer (score -1):

This is a classic example where you can use a **Quick-Union algorithm.**

Computational Limits

- **Time complexity** for grouping N rows : O(N log* N) where log* N is the "number of times needed to take the lg of a number until reaching 1" . eg Log* 10^100 = 3 (approx)
- **Space complexity** : O(N)

Read more on this algorithm:

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MaNCMWhYIHo ,
2. https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/AlgsDS07/01UnionFind.pdf

Comment: Correct, but missing critical help:  To use the union-find algorithm for this problem, make an initial set for each unique Id, and an initial set for each unique type.  Union any two sets that appear in the same row. Assign a groupid to each final set.  The groupid of the row is then the groupid for the final set that contains its id and type sets.  NOTE: I didn't downvote this answer

Comment: On making an initial set for  each unique id, I feel that is a very basic thing for applying the algorithm and anyone who watches the videos I linked will do. And regarding assigning a groupid to each final set, that will be done through the algorithm and you will get unique ids for each groups at the end of the algo.